# Jquery load data from php/json file and append new content to div for chat

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Hi People i try to do a small jquery/php/mysql chat! What i need to do ist following:

1. My Html

```
    <div id="loader"></div>
```

2. My Php

```
     $myArray = array();
        if ($result = $mysqli->Query("SELECT * FROM chat AS CHA LIMIT 3 ")) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    $myArray[] = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($myArray);
        }
```

3. My Json Output

```
    [
      {
        "CHA_id": "594",
        "CHA_to": null,
        "CHA_from": "1000",
        "CHA_time": "2019-11-18 00:02:13",
        "CHA_room": "yes",
        "CHA_read": null,
        "CHA_message": "Message 1"
      },
      {
        "CHA_id": "593",
        "CHA_to": null,
        "CHA_from": "1004",
        "CHA_time": "2019-11-17 23:56:47",
        "CHA_room": "yes",
        "CHA_read": null,
        "CHA_message": "Message 2 "
      },
      {
        "CHA_id": "592",
        "CHA_to": null,
        "CHA_from": "1004",
        "CHA_time": "2019-11-17 23:56:47",
        "CHA_room": "yes",
        "CHA_read": null,
        "CHA_message": "Message 3 "
      }
    ]
```

4. My Jquery
   I try this

```
$.getJSON( "https://example.com/JSON.CHAT.php", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

But i get only this response

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

What i need to do ist 
**1. Load the content into loader div from json output

2. Update div appending  new content based on "CHA_time"**
Every help ist wellcome im totaly blocked.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include your JavaScript code.  Please indicate what you've tried and what specifically isn't working as expected.  Currently it looks like you're just broadly looking for examples of how to use AJAX with jQuery, of which the internet is full of examples.

Comment: Thank you for reply i try meny snipets but nothing

Comment: @RobertMrsic: We can appreciate that you're having difficulty, but "I tried many snippets" doesn't tell us anything about your attempt and "but nothing" doesn't tell us anything about the problem.  If you can elaborate on the specifics of the problem then we can help.

Comment: 1. https://api.jquery.com/load/ 2. Proper _ordering_ of the records should happen in your SQL query already, not afterwards. If you only want the newest entries from a certain timestamp on (like when you last updated the list on the client) - then you should pass that timestamp back from the client to the server, so that you can explicitly select “newer” records only.

Comment: Here i updated what i try and what i get. But i need to get data make html and update loader div . Thank you

Comment: `[object Object]` is what you get, when you try to force a JS object into a string context. You need to access the individual properties of those objects contained in your JSON array, and append the values of those somewhere.

Comment: How i acces to individual propertyes ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This output:

```
[object Object]
```

Is the result of what you're doing here:

```
items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
```

In this case `val` is one of your returned objects:

```
{
    "CHA_id": "594",
    "CHA_to": null,
    "CHA_from": "1000",
    "CHA_time": "2019-11-18 00:02:13",
    "CHA_room": "yes",
    "CHA_read": null,
    "CHA_message": "Message 1"
}
```

But the system has no way to know how to meaningfully display that object as a simple string.  Did you want to display all properties?  With or without keys?  A specific property?  In a specific format?  JavaScript doesn't/can't know.  So you need to specify how to format it.  For example, if you just want to display one field:

```
items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val.CHA_id + "</li>" );
//                                        ^--- here
```

Or if you want to format two fields, separated by a hyphen:

```
items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val.CHA_id + " - " + val.CHA_message + "</li>" );
```

Basically, however you want to format it, you'd need to provide the formatting logic to do that.

Comment: Thank You that ist what i dont know . Can i ask you some other information i hope
So the key = Object  and val are rows of object that right ?

Comment: @RobertMrsic: In your specific code, `key` and `val` are simply the names you assigned to the two parameters of the `$.each()` callback function.  The first parameter is just an incrementing integer (conceptually similar to a basic `for` loop structure), the second parameter is the array element for the array over which you're iterating.

Answer (score 1):

As 04FS metioned, Your JS isn't right. It should be something like this:

```
$.getJSON( "https://example.com/JSON.CHAT.php", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val.CHA_message + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

All "rows" are objects, so each individual value must be used properly while trying to add it to string.